# #e5004f + cover = #720027, x + cover = #e5004f, x =?

Tags: css

Condition:
1. Here is a hexadecimal color : #e5004f
2. Then put a cover on this, color to be "#720027"

Question: 
If put the same cover on color "X", then "X" to be #e5004f, so "X"= ?

Format:

## e5004f + cover = #720027; x + cover = #e5004f; x = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x = #ff0058`.

Use the service at [www.colorhexa.com/](http://www.colorhexa.com/) to quickly calculate color addition/subtraction.

Comment: Thanks for share the website.